# Dajare no "dake ni"

Tags: translation

This question is about puns, or dajare, where at the end of a sentence almost every time there's `dake ni` to be heard. I'm having trouble understanding what role `dake ni` has in these sentences? When translated literally it doesn't make much sense to me. These are all from recent anime I'm watching, for example:

- One is about shougi (将棋): Sugu komacchau, koma dake ni
- One pun was: juudou (柔道) is a sport where every person throws at the same angle, which is juu do (十度), juudou dake ni
- This one was about bicycle club, where when members drive, Okane ga ochite, charin, charin, chari dake ni

So what's `dake ni` doing there? Or rather how should it be translated?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? E.g., WWWJDIC has だけに "as might be expected (from ...); (precisely) because ...; ... being the case".

Comment: That would give "j­ūdō is a sport where every person throws at the same angle, jūdo, as might be expected from jūdō".

Comment: Seems like Tangorin and WWWJDIC use the same database... Well yes, I checked the dictionary, but trying to translate the last one this way will give: `Money go bling bling when falling, as might be expected from a BICYCLE`? That's not a funny pun to me, even considering onomatopeic `charin` and the word `chari`. I think there is more to `dake ni` in puns, which direct translation does not capture. Or I can't understand puns at all.

Comment: Look up "all the more ... because", and you'll see http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=all+the+more+because

Answer (score 1, accepted):

だけに is used when the result that appeared is contrary to the expectation. It's difficult to give an exact meaning for the phrase in these contexts. だけ and だけに can also occur in other contexts as well that are not based on this meaning.

It is often used incorrectly by young Japanese people to make what they are saying seem more interesting.

Comment: Here is an example that だけに　is correctly used:
「予期していなかっただけにショックは大きかった」 
but, when combined with ダジャレ(dajare), does it make sense to you? People 'do' put those words at the end, and they sometimes don't really make sense to us at all. I'm just trying to help. People in Japan would never stab you in the back, we are 武士. But you're doing it by downvoting without giving some comment or explanation why didn't you like it.

Comment: I'm not your downvote, but I think your answering style and/or English level makes it a little hard to follow your answers.

Comment: Thanks, I'm relieved now.
It's really different from StackOverflow.
(I checked your profile. I'm sure what it is)

Comment: I've suggested corrections just for the English. If it were me, I would say だけに can end up meaning "just because" or "only because" in many contexts -- but also sometimes "even though".

Comment: Thanks for your correction for my wiring.
Best way to learn Japanese phrases is to look them up in http://daijirin.dual-d.net/ and translate what it gives you. It's what I use always.

Comment: @hanishi are you saying that `だけに` is just something that people put at the end of puns just to give listeners a hint that it is what it is, and I should not pay too much attention to it? BTW I also didn't downvote you, I appreciate every answer and comment.
@virmaior your comment seems most plausible to me, although the whole meaning is still a little vague to me. With this in mind, first of these puns could be understood as follows: "A shougi piece (`こま`) is always troubled (`こまっちゃう`)". This would make some sense actually, but I just omitted `だけに` entirely...

Comment: Or is it unspoken `Because it's ...` at the beginning of my little translation...?

Comment: I now know which だけに.
将棋の駒だけに「こまっちゃう」others include:
貸さないよ、傘だけに。
寝っころんだな、猫だけに。
Is as much as 傘(no more or less than a 傘）
Is as much as 猫(no more or less than a 猫）
This is how I understand it, but it is not an easy one.

Comment: I think you got it now. That's it.
Because it's 駒(That 'Because' does not make sense, but 駒 and こまっちゃう　lymes)

Comment: On the contrary, it means "as can/might be expected". Even in your example "it was a big shock BECAUSE it wasn't expected"

Comment: @Kitet This is an explanation of another usage of だけに.  Hope it does not confuse you too badly.

Comment: I think I get it, more or less. Thanks everyone - for the answer and comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think the point of this *dake ni* is to underline the apparent meaning, the "double meaning", by treating it as the real one. To give a really terrible English example "He put dents in my teeth - just as you'd expect of a dentist". It isn't that you would really expect that of a dentist, but that in the "world" of the joke dentist means "person who makes dents".